# Dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 and CentOS 7.0

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, centos

Problem in installing Ubuntu after CentOS 7.0: I have a laptop with a hard disk around 170Gb. After installing CentOS 7.0 I tried to install the Ubuntu 14.04 alongside with the CentOS 7.0. The Ubuntu installer could not recognise the existing CentOS 7.0 and I could not shrink the exisitng drive.

Will change of installation sequence helps (remove the CentOS 7.0 and install Ubuntu first)?

Comment: If Ubuntu definitely doesn't recognise your CentOS install, then boot with the CentOS install media and use that to shrink the parition(s). Hopefully, Ubuntu will then see the free space.

Comment: Interesting that Ubuntu doesn't recognize lvm partitions...I assume that is what you have with CentOS as it is the default. For my own curiosity, what does Ubuntu call that chunk of data then?

Answer (score 1):

Order of installation should not matter. You should boot to a live USB or CD/DVD some Linux OS, install GParted, and shrink the CentOS partition from there. Then you can install Ubuntu in the free space you just created.

Source: I personally have Windows 7, Ubuntu, and Fedora on my desktop. Live media partitioning always works best for me.